# missing some folders in iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I am developing an iOS project. There, I am having to upload images to to PHP server. So I choose some images from gallery in  simulator for check up. Selected image is stored inside simulator. But I couldn't find that folder. So image is going empty to server. How  to find that folders?

That image stored path is below

```
User/Guest/Library/developer/core simulator/devices/1ABD8156-4A55-4189--BDCD-DA6F7CSB2229/data/containers/data/applications/1559E24-9738-447D-8888-EEC9E29D4D39/Documents/Photo.jpg
```

But here I can  found until

```
User/Guest/Library/developer/core simulator/devices/1ABD8156-4A55-4189--BDCD-DA6F7CSB2229/data/containers/data/applications/
```

How can I solve this. Please help me.

Note: i am using xamarin studio for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would get u the simulator directory.

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

Comment: sorry. i am new to ios .. pls say me how to use this code. thanks for your help

Comment: ok. now i got System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException. how to  solve this?

Comment: it means ur directory is not present . You just print ur simulator path on ur console and see if it is matching.

Comment: i printed and find that path inside simulator too. there is some image. when i try to upload any of that image, this error coming.

Comment: any other ways to  upload the image from imageview to server directly? i meant without storing the selected image   inside simulator

Comment: i want to upload the image on imageview to server. what is simplest way?

Comment: u could convert image to  NSdata and send that image

Comment: i use mac using vnc. so i couldn't paste the code to windows. pls give up

Comment: pls give me some code for convert image into NSdata

Comment: UIImage *img = yourImageView.image;
    NSData *image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.1);